# Query changed since last execution in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have a dataset created in SSRS using VS 2017.  After the initial code created in query builder, I go the text window to add in a COUNT function.  As soon as I do this, I start getting a text window with the old code intermittently blinking with the new changes.  A warning triangle appears in the top cell of the row selector column that says "Query changed from last execution" once I hover over the triangle.  Once this happens, the window will not allow any changes.

This is, no doubt, a bug.  I also experienced this in VS 2019.  Since I can close out of VS 2017, reboot, re-open the report, the intermittent blinking still occurs.  What I have is a corrupted report and have to delete it.  I want to avoid having to create and delete projects based on a bug that I cannot find any resolution for.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

[image: See a screenshot of my issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same problem.
Was able to fix it by using "Stored procedure" instead of "Text" in Dataset properties window.

Comment: I have gotten away from having to use the Text window and now only use stored procs